# How to pass an input to Redux store and map filtered data accordingly

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I am having trouble passing an object from the Parent to Child component.
I have read various similar posts but none of the solutions did work.

Error message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Parent: (App.js)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchData } from '../actions/actions';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      filter: "",
      data: [],
      filteredData: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchData());
  };

  render() {

    const { filter, data } = this.state;
    const lowercasedFilter = filter.toLowerCase();
    const filteredData = data.filter(item => {
      return Object.keys(item).some(key =>
        item[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(lowercasedFilter)
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <UserList filteredData={filteredData}/>
        {console.log(this.props.myData.Brastlewark)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ things: { myData, isFetching } }) => ({
  myData,
  isFetching
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Child: (Userlist.js)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchData } from '../actions/actions';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import '../layout.css'

class UserList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      filter: "",
      data: [],
      filteredData: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchData());
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ filter: event.target.value });
    this.setState((state, props) => ({
      data: this.props.myData.Brastlewark
    }))
  };

  render() {
    const {filteredData} = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="jumbotron">
          <h2>
            <input value={this.props.filter} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="please search" />
          </h2>
            {!this.props.isFetching && <div> You may start searching for Orcs in the vilage by typing into the search box above. </div>}
        </div>

        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
              {filteredData.map(item => (
              <div className="col-md-4 col-xs-6" key={item.id}>
                <div className="card">
                    <img className="card-img-top img-fluid" src={item.thumbnail} alt={item.age}/>
                  <div className="card-block">
                    <h5 className="card-title">{item.professions.toString().split(', ')}</h5>
                    <p className="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                    <p className="card-text"><small className="text-muted">Last updated 1 sec ago</small></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      {console.log(this.props.myData.Brastlewark)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ things: { myData, isFetching } }) => ({
  myData,
  isFetching
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserList);
```

Action.js

```
export const REQUEST_DATA = 'REQUEST_DATA'; // action to represent waiting for response
export const GET_DATA_FIRST = 'GET_DATA_FIRST'; // action to represent receiving of data

export const requestData = () => ({ type: REQUEST_DATA });

export const getDataFirst = myData => ({ type: GET_DATA_FIRST, myData });

export const fetchData = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestData());
    return getData().then(things => {
    // simulated delay
    setTimeout(() => {
        return dispatch(getDataFirst(things))
    }, 1000);
});
};

const getData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rrafols/mobile_test/master/data.json');
    return await res.json();
}
```

Reducer (reducer.js)

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { GET_DATA_FIRST, REQUEST_DATA } from '../actions/actions';

const initialState = {
  isFetching: false,
  myData: []
};

const things = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST_DATA:
        return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true
        };
    case GET_DATA_FIRST:
        return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        myData: action.myData
        };
    default:
        return state;
  }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  things // this key can be called anything, 'things' is just an example
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Perhaps somebody could help me converting this part to redux or just the simplest way, getting filtedData defined by input text?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In which file does the error happened?

Comment: The second. Userlist.js

Comment: You have to debug it. It make no sense because it seems filteredData should be empty array initialy

Comment: The filteredData variable should be passed from Parent to Children. I am just trying to separate logic from presentation the best I can.

Comment: `const { filter, data } = this.state;` You're filtering from `data` which is from the `App` state, which you're not using/setting anywhere. You're fetching from both the `App` and the `UserList` which doesn't make much sense. The `UserList` is handling the `filter` but it's the parent that's trying to filter... This is not a matter of state or redux, the logic is just incoherent in these two components. Clean them up a little, debug the data you're using before using it (like filtering, etc) and you should be able to figure it out on your own.

Comment: [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) documentation page could help as well.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Can you post a answer? I will accept

Comment: You're encouraged to post an answer to your own question and accept it if you succeeded in fixing the problem!

Comment: @EmileBergeron Can you see my profile, please?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that the `.map` function is running before the `data` is passed. This error usually appears when you try to go through an undefined object.

Try this code:

```
<div className="row">
    {filteredData && filteredData.map(item => (
        // do stuff with your item
    ))}
</div>
```

Mentioning the name of a variable before actually doing something with it checks whether is is `undefined/null` or not. If it's not, it will go on and do what you have programmed it to do.

Comment: The error is gone, I can see the searchbar but cannot even console.log(item)  inside the block I should do stuff with the item though.  This data should be returned from the parent component and from the input box and updated on the child. We are almost there and I will accept your question asap

Comment: Please state exactly what you want to pass in and where. In your code you were using the `.map` function to render all the items in `filteredData`. In case your want your Redux `store` to be updated whenever you click on an item or something, your are going to need to import an Action.

Comment: I am adding my Action.js file

Comment: I want to pass values typed in the <input> box into the filteredData object so I can map them

Comment: Note that the error above had to do with rendering your component. Passing it to your Redux `state` should be done outside the `render` function. What you need is a `Reducer` to change your `store`'s state. See the [Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers/).

Comment: Change the thread's title to 'HOW TO PASS AN INPUT TO REDUX STORE AND MAP FILTERED DATA ACCORDINGLY'.